# C# - Downloaded zip file is invalid

Tags: c#, zip

I am downloading zip file with `WebClient`:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())  
{  
    client.DownloadFile("https://mods.factorio.com" + mod.release.downloadUrl, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), mod.release.fileName));  
}
```

Path is correct but when I go to file to open it, it says invalid zip file.

Comment: It is downloaded correctly if you download the same url with, say, `curl`? Also: don't you need to be logged into the mod portal to download factorio mods (which `WebClient` won't be)? Or is that just to install them into the game?

Comment: Have you tried to download manually and verified that the file is not corrupted?

Comment: Most likely you are not downloading the entire zip before attempting to open.  Check byte count and see if the size is same as original file.

Comment: @MarcGravell no its dont need to be logged in but it dont has exactly same size as file downloaded manually

Comment: @jdwengIts no its diferrent

Comment: Have you opened the file in a text editor to see if its a textual error response/html?

Comment: @AlexK. it has some html in it and there is some form to login but in wiki says "Using the API does not require any kind of authentication or account information and can be viewed simply by following the URLs below in any web browser."

Comment: So that's the problem then, make sure your using the correct API URL.

Comment: @AlexK. Thats strange, they says no authentication but it requires it

Comment: If you solved your own question, put the answer in the “Your Answer” box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer; that marks your question as answered in the UI. Adding “SOLVED” to the title does not mark your question as answered.

Comment: @MineGame159 it might be that the API for *metadata* (i.e. the list of plugins and their descriptions) doesn't require login, but actually *downloading* a plugin: does. Also: great game :)